# Realize a Bootstrap input combined with badge pill with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I realize that the badge appears where I want it?

What are the CSS Class Parameters?

This is my html so far:

```
    <input id="<?php echo $this->id; ?>" type="<?php echo $this->type; ?>" class="form-control mr-sm-2 lg" id="<?php echo $this->id; ?>" name="<?php echo $this->name; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $this->placeholder; ?>">
        <span id="<?php echo $this->badge_id; ?>" class="position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-info text dark">
            <span class="badge bg-info text-dark">
            </span>
        </span>
    </input>
```

The Input is inside a jumbotron and container. First of a bunch ... input comes with a scanned barcode or manually

Read the BS Documentation so far tried different html, did develope many BS Elements in other context..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, did find a simple solution as the BS "out of the Box" Element was not working for me with an input Element:

Downsized the badge class from:

```
<span class="position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle p-2 bg-danger border border-light rounded-circle"></span>
```

to:

```
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary" id="element"></span>
```

Give em an ID an post your designated information inner HTML. This works above the Element you want to stick the badge on.